# Render view different to viewport shading

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I'm new to Blender and lack the technical knowledge probably to explain very well so I'll try to attach the blend file to help hopefully.

I have a short animation of a man jumping through a glass door (have keyframed the glass to become visible on frame 16.  My issue is that in the viewport shading the glass is transparent and the alpha movie of the guy behind is clear and unwrapped.

f however you render that particular frame the rendered image is much different, the glass isn't transparent and the figure is warped.  Once the animation of the glass starts and shatters more it is okay but that frame makes it look weird.  Is there an easy way to make the rendered view look the same as the viewport shading view?

[File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hp71vaft2atihsu/GLASS-BUST2.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I essentially want the rendered image (specifically frame 16) to look the same as the viewport shading image.  They look different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what makes it look less transparent is that Plane in the Collection collection. It's hidden in the viewport, but it should be Disabled in render too.

Let me know if that's it!
Welcome to Blender!!

EDIT: I can confirm that both objects should be Disabled in Render.
[image: Disable those planes]

Comment: Hi Dahm,  you legend, thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all glass is meant to be transparent. To fix the image problems u need to unplug alpha from the image texture. to unwrap it press tab - a - u - unwrap. if u need more help unwrapping check out this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM)

hope this helped! :D